# closestParent method always returns 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, recursion, ecmascript-6, closest

I'm havin' hard times to write a function (or more specific an ES6 Class Method) that returns an elements closest parent matching a specified selector.

My function recursively calls itself again until the wanted class is found in the current elements `classList` property.

If I log the element I get the exact element I want, but if I log the function call itself it always returns `undefined`.

Here is my code:

```
findParent (element, selector) {
    if (element === document) return null // stops when at end of tree
    if (element.classList.contains('foo-selector')) {
      console.log(element)  // logs the expected element
      return element // returns 'undefined'
    }
    this.findParent(element.parentNode) // function calls itself again
}
```

I experimented a bit and looked at different implementations of getClosest functions and discovered a working one that uses a **for loop**. But apart from that it's using  a very similar approach.

This takes me to the conclusion that I'm doing something wrong with the recursion; I just can't see what...
Any ideas?

Comment: Your recursion doesn't work. Neither do you pass on your parameters, nor do you return its result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your not returning it when you call it again. Change it like this:

```
findParent (element, selector) {
    if (element === document) return null // stops when at end of tree
    if (element.classList.contains('foo-selector')) {
      console.log(element)  // logs the expected element
      return element // returns 'undefined'
    }
    return this.findParent(element.parentNode) // function calls itself again
}
```

Comment: I had to pass `selector` again to the call in the last line but that error is on me ;) so thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to return from the point where you are calling the recursive function again

```
findParent (element, selector) {
    if (element === document) return null // stops when at end of tree
    if (element.classList.contains('foo-selector')) {
      console.log(element)  // logs the expected element
      return element 
    }
    return this.findParent(element.parentNode) 
}
```